# Logout Facebook in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

var loginUrl =  "https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next=google.com.vn" + "&access_token=" +  HttpUtility.UrlEncode(AccessToken);
AuthenticationBrowser.Navigate(new Uri(loginUrl));
AuthenticationBrowser.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

it's not logout facebook.  It navigate to  facebook homepage, who help me solve it? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A trick you can use to logout can be by *forgetting* the `AccessToken`. i.e. when you wish to logout u can set the token to `""` [empty string].